# Having trouble with "replaceall" command

Tags: java

I have a string

```
s1 = "7+8";
```

and

```
s2 = "7+";
```

I am using the following code to subtract s2 from s1

```
System.out.println(s1.replaceAll(s2,""));
```

but it is giving output as

```
"+8"
```

Why is this happening??

Comment: @DavidWallace Well I was talking about how embarrassing it was when *I* post stupid answers, which I do a lot...

Comment: I have posted (at least) two factual errors in the last 24 hours.  It happens to all of us.  Don't give it another thought.

Answer (score 3):

The regular expression `"7+"` matches one or more instances of `"7"`.  This is what is replaced, leaving `"+8"`.

If you want to match exact strings, rather than regular expressions, use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`.

```
s1.replace(s2, "")
```

Comment: Yes, there is, but why bother?

Comment: Right; sorry about that. I'm not actually sure what I was thinking of. Too many "replace"s in too many APIs...

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that the method [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) uses a *regex* (regular expression) to determine what to replace.

> **String java.lang.String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement):**
>   Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

**What can you do?** You may want to use the method [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) that uses strings *literally* to replace:

```
System.out.println(s1.replace(s2, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to your question (Why is this happening??), String.replaceAll takes a RegEx as first parameter.

You may want to use String.replace

`System.out.println(s1.replace(s2, ""));`

Comment: yes,replace worked for me,thanks.And also i get to know the reason.

Comment: Glad it worked. Please consider accepting the answer which helped you.